# Can you help the woman with two children escape from the jail?

Tags: the-witcher-2

While escaping from the jail after Geralt remembers his death, I ran across a cell with a woman who begged for me help her escape because she has two children.  After I picked the lock, she sat down.  I can no longer interact with the door and she doesn't follow me out.  Am I missing something?  I thought for sure she would come out and give me something (since she says she'll "do anything").

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If she's just there for the ambience, it'll be a great to have a DLC to expand it into a full quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I passed this place it seemed that her loud speech would draw guard's attention. And Geralt doesn't pick the lock, he calms the woman to be quiet to keep his runaway silent.

Comment: Indeed, the option that is shown is something like 'calm down the lady'

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed that.  I had the resolution pretty low.